# Merge tables created with ListTable in php

Tags: php, mysql, css, mysqli

I have five tables which are made by function ListTable in php.

I have function ListTable3, where is one query and table rows for results.

```
function ListTable3($db, $host, $user, $pass, $start_vceraj, $end_vceraj, $start_danes, $end_danes, $start_date_danes, $start_date_vceraj, $trenutni_cas)
{
   query("some query");
   $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
      {
        $output .=<table>
          results rows 
        $output .=</table>
      };
}
```

Then i call this function ListTable3 with for loop, because i call same function five times, only from diferent database. I created an array of databases, and now in for loop i am calling same funtion ListTable3 for all databases, one by one.

Code:

```
$db_array = array($db_one,$db_two,$db_three,$db_four,$db_five);
for($y=0; $y < $st_db_array; $y++)
    {   
        if($db_array[$y]!= $db_one)
            {
                $host=$host;
            }
        else {
            $host = $host_one;
        }
        print "<tr>";   
        print "<td>";
          $output = ListTable3($db_array[$y], $host, $user, $pass, $start_vceraj, $end_vceraj, $start_danes, $end_danes, $start_date_danes, $start_date_vceraj, $trenutni_cas);
        print $output;
        print "</td>";  
        print "</tr>";
    }
```

So when i run my page, i got five tables with data but they are not merged.

I'd like to get one table where would be table heading, and then those five tables from for loop merged together in one. Can any one give me any suggestions or sollutions how should i do it?

Here is a picture of what i have, and what i need to do: http://postimg.org/image/jmmo5viuf/

Thanks everyone for help

Comment: Just move `<table>` and `</table>` out of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Separate your query logic from the display logic:

```
$data = array();
foreach($things_to_query as $thing) {
   $newdata = listtable3($thing);
   array_merge($data, $newdata); // you'll have to mod this
}
foreach($data) {
   ... display stuff here...
}
```

And note that as written, your listtable3 function will never work. `$mysqli` is undefined, which'd make all of your queries fail.